# how to inherit Qt UI file in another UI file

Tags: qt

I have created 'base.ui' file in QT designer and I want to inherit this 'base.ui' file in another 'UI' file.Is there any way to do it

Comment: Please define what *"inherit*" means in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None that I know of - what I think you're trying to do is use a custom widget inside of another yea?

You can extend the designer via plugins, I'm more familiar with PyQt's syntax or I would give you a coding example, but read up on this:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.0-snapshot/adding-plugins.html

and:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/designer-using-custom-widgets.html

The general idea is that your one UI file is defining the interface for a subclass of a QWidget.  You'll then use your new QWidget subclass as a part of another QWidget subclass, and display its UI contents in designer via a plugin.